# glossary not showing

Tags: bibliographies, errors, glossaries, overleaf

I am trying to create a simple document with glossary and bibliography. I basically merged two example online ( i am completely new to latex). Firstly i created the glossary and all worked just fine. Then when i added the bibliography my glossary dissapeared. Any idea why and how I can fix it? I am working in Overleaf and do not get any error with this code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[round]{natbib}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    % glossary
    \usepackage[xindy]{glossaries} 
    \input{glossary}
    \makeglossaries

\title{LaTeX Bibliography Example: The natbib Package}
\author{writeLaTeX}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Here are some natbib examples. You can cite examples using the citation key \citep{TM83} in your .bib file. (On writeLaTeX, you can access the .bib file via the Project menu.) There are commands for in-text citations, like \citet{GMP81}. And you can pass an option to specify additional details, such as a page or chapter number, as an option \citep[p. 130]{Ful83}.

\printglossaries

% To change the title from References to Bibliography:
\newpage
\renewcommand\refname{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % or try abbrvnat or unsrtnat
\bibliography{example} % refers to example.bib

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Thank you for providing a minimal working example (MWE) but it would also help if you could include the contents of `glossary.tex`. You don't have any instances of `\gls`. The glossary will only contain entries that have been indexed in the document using commands like `\gls`.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Glossaries are not printed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/305370).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glossaries are not printed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305370/glossaries-are-not-printed)