# Multiples of the Same Entry with Multiple Glossaries

Tags: glossaries

So I'm putting together my thesis and I'm fairly new at Latex. I'm trying to compile a glossary (labelled as List of Terms) and list of acronyms in the front, and an index in the back. But the index keeps tagging the page number for the list of acronyms and printing certain entries twice.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,lot,lof]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[nopostdot,nogroupskip,acronyms,toc]{glossaries} %Make glossaries

\newglossary[tlg]{index}{tld}{tdn}{Index}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand*{\maketerms}{
  \setglossarystyle{index}
  \printglossary[title=LIST OF TERMS, toctitle=List of Terms,nonumberlist]
  \glsaddall
}

\newcommand*{\makeloa}{
  \renewcommand*{\glossarypreamble}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
  \setglossarystyle{alttree}
  \glssetwidest{YYYYYYY}
  \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS, toctitle=List of Abbreviations,nonumberlist]
}

\newcommand*{\makeind}{
  \setglossarystyle{index}
  \printglossary[type=index,title=INDEX,toctitle=Index]
  \glsaddallunused
}

\input{ch-appendicies/Terms.tex}
\input{ch-appendicies/Index.tex}

\begin{document}
  \bodyspacing
  \maketerms\makeloa
  \makeind %Makes index
\end{document}
```

The `Terms.tex` file has my glossary and list of acronyms entries

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's better. I'm trying not to add the whole program because that would be really long. But I added the document part so I think it should run.

Comment: It is still a fragment only

Comment: `\glsaddall` indexes every defined entry, so page 1 (or whatever page `\maketerms` is on) will appear in the location list for every entry. Any use of `\gls` in the document then adds to the location list. Then `\glsaddallunused`(in `\makeind`) iterates over every defined entry and indexes any entries that haven't been marked as used, which is redundant. If you haven't unset any entries this is a pointless loop and if you have, you end up with hidden locations added to the location lists.

Comment: I thought that at first, but then when I remove all `\glsaddall` and `\glsaddallunused`, the index compiles fine, but the other two glossaries don't compile at all. Edit: Rather, the other two glossaries compile as a single blank page.

Comment: @Tim You need to include some of the definitions provided in `Terms.tex` and `Index.tex` in your question. Otherwise it's difficult to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Related: [Glossaries are not printed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/305370)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The issue was that I wasn't actually using `\gls` to tag my terms in the text, I was just using `\gls{tld:<label>}` to input them in the index, so the glossary was compiling as empty unless I used `\glsaddall`, which created all the other issues.

Thank you @Nicola Talbot, your comments helped me hone in on the issue. I'll try to format my questions better next time.